# Elementor JavaScript change image when Accordion clicked

Tags: javascript, elementor

[solved, view working code below]
I am trying to change an img src when an Accordion item is selected in elementor.
The code I currently have would appear to me as being correct, but it's not working. Probably an obvious fix. It's important not to use JQuery.

my Accordion has 3 "tabs" with an img next to the widget, each tab has an ID #part1 #part2 #part3. And the img has an ID "img_swap".

Javascript code sample for 1 image (now working)

```
    <script>

document.getElementById("part1").onmousedown = function () {
  
  
    document.getElementById("img_swap").getElementsByTagName("img")[0].src="some_image";

};

    </script>
```

Comment: you are using getElement**s**ByClassName and expecting the result to be one single object instead of a collection. Plus if you needed further help it would appreaciated if you included more details.. including the corresponding html

Comment: you are correct, my bad. I have updated the code with the working js.

Answer (score 0):

solved

```
    <script>

document.getElementById("part1").onmousedown = function () {
  
  
    document.getElementById("img_swap").getElementsByTagName("img")[0].src="some_image";

};

    </script>
```